# How to create multiple alias for child table in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my company we actually transfer materials between warehouses referring a particular Production Order number. When entering a production order the materials transferred between different workstations would appear in rows .

```
select
    ste.production_order as "Production Order:Link/Production Order:120",
    ste_item.qty as "Qty:Float:60",
ste_item.s_warehouse as "Source Warehouse:Data:120",
    ste_item.t_warehouse as "Target Warehouse:Data:120"
        
from
    `tabStock Entry` ste INNER JOIN `tabStock Entry Detail` ste_item ON ( ste.name = ste_item.parent and ste.docstatus = 1 and ste.purpose in ('Material Transfer'))
```

[Different warehouses as rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALnA1.png)

now I planned to create alias for the child table Stock Entry Detail so that I could select warehouses from the first alias and add warehouses adjacent so instead of appearing in rows everything would appear in columns.But creating alias for the child table displays nothing .

I tried with this code :

```
select
    ste.production_order as "Production Order:Link/Production Order:120",
    ste_item.qty as "Cutting Qty:Float:60",
    ste_item1.qty as "Forging Qty:Float:60"
        
from
    `tabStock Entry` ste JOIN `tabStock Entry Detail` ste_item ON ( ste.name = ste_item.parent and ste.docstatus = 1 and  ste_item.t_warehouse in ('Cutting - OMMIFORGE'))

JOIN `tabStock Entry Detail` ste_item1 ON ( ste.name = ste_item1.parent and ste.docstatus = 1 and  ste_item1.t_warehouse in ('Forging - OMMIFORGE'))
```

Guys any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `left join`:

```
select ste.production_order as "Production Order:Link/Production Order:120",
       ste_item.qty as "Cutting Qty:Float:60",
       ste_item1.qty as "Forging Qty:Float:60"   
from `tabStock Entry` ste left join
     `tabStock Entry Detail`
     ste_item 
     on ste.name = ste_item.parent and
        ste.docstatus = 1 and
        ste_item.t_warehouse in ('Cutting - OMMIFORGE') left join
     `tabStock Entry Detail` ste_item1 
     on ste.name = ste_item1.parent and
        ste.docstatus = 1 and
        ste_item1.t_warehouse in ('Forging - OMMIFORGE');
```

Comment: I already tried LEFT JOIN and all sorts of JOIN statements, only JOIN and INNER JOIN provides the relevant results and in this case , the JOIN statement for the second alias does not work . Kindly guide me. Thanks

Comment: Really I am not able to make out . Mysql works strangely in this case ? Could you please guide me ? Thanks